# Calculating spectrum $f\mapsto (1-x)f$

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $\Lambda:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ by
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda(f)(x)=(1-x)\cdot f(x).
\end{equation*}
What is the spectrum of $\Lambda$? I think the spectrum is $[0,1].$ This case is very similar to the case when $f\mapsto xf$. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. $T-\lambda I$ has a bounded inverse iff $\lambda \notin [0,1]$ and the inverse in this case is $f(x) \to \frac  1 {1-x-\lambda} f(x)$.